# Método C# uso de SSH.NET problemas en al añadir strings a un fichero

Tags: c#, ssh

Estoy haciendo un método en C# que añada información a un fichero que se encuentra en una máquina con Ubuntu Server. Para ello estoy haciendo uso de SSH.NET . En modo debug si lo voy ejecutándolo paso a paso todo funciona correctamente, el problema surge cuando lo ejecuto "de seguido", en el fichero "logFile" sólo se añaden algunas líneas, para ser exactos sólo segunda componente del array de strings.

```
   public static void ExecSSH(string pServidor, string pUsuario, string pPassword, string[] changes)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new SshClient(pServidor, pUsuario,pPassword))
            {
                client.Connect();
                //Necesario para hacer acciones de super usuario
                ShellStream shellStream = client.CreateShellStream("xterm", 80, 24, 800, 600, 1024);
                var output = shellStream.Expect(new Regex(@"[$>]"));

                //Obtener privilegios de super usuario"
                shellStream.WriteLine("sudo su");
                output = shellStream.Expect(new Regex(@"([$#>:])"));

                //Comprobación por si ya se estaba en modo Super usuario
                if(output.IndexOf("password") != -1)
                {
                    //Si no se estaba en super usuario se introduce la contraseña
                    shellStream.WriteLine(pPassword);
                }
                //Crear fichero de log si no se ha creado antes
                shellStream.WriteLine("touch /var/log/asterisk/" + logFile);
                //Cambiar los permisos para que cualquier usuario pueda modificar el fichero
                shellStream.WriteLine("chmod 646 /var/log/asterisk/"+ logFile);

                //Recorrer array de strings para añadir cada componente en una linea del fichero
                for(int i = 0; i < changes.Length; i++)
                {
                    //Cambia los $ que haya en las strings para que los reconozca
                    string valuechange = changes[i].Replace("$","\\$");

                    //Añadir ese componente del array en una linea del fichero

                    shellStream.WriteLine("echo " + valuechange + " >> " + "/var/log/asterisk/" + logFile);

                }
               client.Disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { throw ex; }
    }
```

He estado googleando y no encuentro qué es lo que puede estar pasando. No sé si puede ser que al servidor no le da tiempo a ejecutar un comando de bash cuando ya le llega el siguiente comando, pero me parece demasiada coincidencia que siempre se añada sólo la segunda componente del array de strings.

Este es el posible contenido del array de strings:

```
string[] change_log = { "\"["+stimenow+"]\"", "\"Category: " + category + "\"", "\"Line: " + line + "\"", "\"LastValue: " + lasvalue +"\"", "\"NewValue1: " + newvalue1 + "\"", "\"NewValue2: " + newvalue1 + "\"" };
```

(Todas las variables de las que depende son strings)

Comment: tiene toda la pinta de que no le das tiempo al otro lado a ejecutar. no hay una libreria asincronica para hacer esto? si no, vas a tener que poner tu programa a dormir unos segundos para darle tiempo..

Comment: He probado a poner Thread.Sleep después de cada comando y efectivamente funciona perfectamente. El problema es que no creo que esta sea una solución viable, ya que no siempre tardará el mismo tiempo el servidor en responder... Intentaré hacer lo mismo con "Renci.SshNet.Async". Gracias